# Is there a way to know which classes are created with `new` when visiting bytecode?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I want to compute all dependencies for a class by visiting its bytecode, in `ClassVisitor` there are visitors for method, fields, attributes, etc, but cannot find when a class is used by calling the new constructor, e.g `this.add(new MyComponent("Hi"))` I would like that `MyComponent` is used, thus I need this dependency to be listed in my results.

btw, I'm using `org.objectweb.asm` version `7.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do that directly with a `ClassVisitor`, but you'd need a `MethodVisitor`. You return a MethodVisitor instance from your ClassVisitor's [`visitMethod`](https://github.com/consulo/objectweb-asm/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.java#L304). There you can implement the [`visitTypeInsn`](https://github.com/consulo/objectweb-asm/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.java#L357) method and check if the parameter `opcode == Opcodes.NEW`.

```
void visitTypeInsn(final int opcode, final String type)
```